# Microfocus COBOL - _mFldhandle - Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: c, linux, cobol, rhel8, microfocus

We are porting an application from HPUX to Linux using Microfocus COBOL and GNU C on both platforms.One of our shared libraries is failing at runtime with the following error:

AB123: symbol lookup error. libRTS.so: undefined symbol: _mFldhandle

My understanding is that _mFldhandle is internal to Microfocus.
Can anyone point me to why we might be having an issue / what we should be including to make sure _mFldhandle is available at runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your MicroFocus COBOL installation is broken. I'd recommend to check with its support´for (re-)installation of the product.
If you linked libRTS.so or another component (commonly cobrun) on your own then it seems like an entry is missing/wrong there (watch out for 32/64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comments from above the usual reason for this symbol being missing is not using "cob" to link your exe or shared object.

The other reason is not using the same 'C' compiler that the product was created with.